# Get values from other sheets in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add values from a few sheets of same cell reference.

I get `#VALUE!` on executing this piece of code.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    x = 0

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        x = x + Sheets(i).Range(rng).Value   
    Next i

    mySUM = x
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line right?

```
x = x + Sheets(i).Range(rng).Value
```

`Range(rng)` does not work unless `rng` contains an address. E.g. `"D1:D3"`

Variable `rng` does not contain a value and that is why your code breaks.

If it is the same address in every sheet you should just write it. e.g. `Range("D1:D3")`